# System.Convert.FromBase64String() accepts some invalid strings as input. Is this a bug in .Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, base64, decoding

.Net's implementation of Convert.FromBase64String() can be fed an invalid input and will produce output without throwing a FormatException. Most invalid input is caught correctly but this type is not. In this case FromBase64String will ignore the last 4 bits of the input string. This can cause multiple inputs to decode to the same byte array.

The issue is demonstrated in this code:

```
var validBase64 = Convert.FromBase64String("TQ==");//assigned length 1 byte array with single byte 0x4d
var invalidBase64 = Convert.FromBase64String("TR==");//also assigned the same
var validConvertedBack = Convert.ToBase64String(validBase64);//assigned TQ==
var invalidConvertedBack = Convert.ToBase64String(validBase64);//assigned TQ==
```

This occurs for the reason explained in this image:

[image]

The first 2 bytes of 'Q' (0,1) are used but the next 4 are ignored. Any character that starts with 0,1 will therefore decode to the same byte array such as R (0,1,0,0,0,1).

The Base64 encoding rfc does not define decoding, only encoding so .Net is not in violation of that spec. However the spec does warn that a similar issue is dangerous:

[>   The padding step in base 64 and base 32 encoding can, if improperly
implemented, lead to non-significant alterations of the encoded data.
For example, if the input is only one octet for a base 64 encoding,
then all six bits of the first symbol are used, but only the first
two bits of the next symbol are used.  These pad bits MUST be set to
zero by conforming encoders, which is described in the descriptions
on padding below.  If this property do not hold, there is no
canonical representation of base-encoded data, and multiple base-
encoded strings can be decoded to the same binary data.  If this
property (and others discussed in this document) holds, a canonical
encoding is guaranteed.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-3.5)

Is Microsoft aware of this functionality? If not, could this be a security issue?

Comment: "Invalid" and "not canonical" are different concepts... Your sample so far shows that encoding provides *canonical* output, while decoding accepts both canonical and not-canonical (but *valid*) strings. There is no example of *invalid* string. You may want to update your question to clarify that...

Comment: As near as I can tell, this question is basically asking "is it a bug that .NET's base64 decoder accepts non-canonical input?" Surely that is about as "primarily opinion based" as they come.

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov I am using MSDN terminology here. See [MSDN on FromBase64String.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string(v=vs.110).aspx)